# TListViewItem images disappearing after Android intent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When using the a third party app to scan via intents for an ANDROID application built with DELPHI XE7, after the scan intent finishes, bitmap images for a TListview disappear ( appear blank ) after the intent finishes. Any ideas as to why or how to fix?

I'm not sure which code is most relevant to this type of situation ( intent vs the way I add images to the listviewitems).

```
for i := 0 to length(AllParts)-1 do
  begin
    AllParts[i].LItem_ADDED:=false;
    LItem:=PartList.items.add;
    LItem.Detail:= DetailCaption;
    LItem.Text:=AllParts[i].ID;
    LItem.ButtonText:=AllParts[i].REORDER_QTY;
    LItem.Bitmap:=AddImage.MakeScreenshot;
  end;
```

Make screenshot is delphi function:

```
function TControl.MakeScreenshot: TBitmap;
var
  SceneScale: Single;
begin
  if Scene <> nil then
    SceneScale := Scene.GetSceneScale
  else
    SceneScale := 1;
  Result := TBitmap.Create(Round(Width * SceneScale), Round(Height * SceneScale));
  Result.BitmapScale := SceneScale;
  Result.Clear(0);
  if Result.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try
    PaintTo(Result.Canvas, TRectF.Create(0, 0, Result.Width / SceneScale, Result.Height / SceneScale));
  finally
    Result.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to do `LItem.Bitmap.Assign(AddImage.MakeScreenshot);` except not sure since I can't see all that code. The thing is, your assignment is only referencing the pointer to the image, which for all I know might be free'd later. Can you show what's behind `MakeScreenshot`? Because you might also have a memory leak there.

Comment: I just tried the 'assign' method and it didn't work. Thanks though. I updated the post as well to include source for the 'MakeScreenshot' function.